# Find a JSON property name that starts with something using JSON Path

Tags: javascript, node.js, xpath, jsonpath

Is it possible to find a property **name** that matches a regex pattern (or at least starts with) using JSON Path.  In XPath I can use `name()` but I haven't been able to find the [JSON Path](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) equivalent.

Basically, I what to find all property names that start with `x-`.  Something like `$..x-*`.

I'll be interested in using any **javascript package** that does this.  Currently, I'm using [JSONPath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONPath).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From my googling this is not possible in standard `json path`.  However, the  [jsonpath-plus](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath-plus) package extends the specification with `@path`; and makes the following possible

```
$..[?(@path.includes("[\'x-"))]
$..*[?(@property === 'price' && @ !== 8.95)]
```

The above assumes you are using [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes).

Answer (score 8):

Useful to someone else 
You can use regular expression using =~ left matches regular expression.  For more in formation visit https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath

```
[?(@.name =~ /foo.*?/i)]
```