# Regex: expected character: )

Tags: regex, jsonpath

I am trying to search after a html tag(creating a JsonPath), but I am missing smth:

```
$..BodyVariables[*].Value[?(@.VALUE=/^<array name=\"AOI\">.*/)].VALUE
```

I want all the VALUEs which begin with "array name=\"AOI\""
and can have anything after. I tried to write this regex in different forms, but no success. I am testing using: http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ 
(e.g. : @..book[?(@.author=/^abc.*/)].author)

Comment: Replace `=` with `=~`. Probably `<` should be removed, are the brackets part of the text?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this web site](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html) the regex matching requires `=~` and not `=`.

If you replace your search query with `@..book[?(@.author=~/^N.*/)].author` you get a match.

Comment: Acc. [to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33933205/find-a-json-property-name-that-starts-with-something-using-json-path), it is also true, so this post is a duplicate. No need re-answering.